# Compare a dynamically driven value in XSL

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

Im using XSLt to transform a table and XML data to show in the UI page, This is my question

```
<xsl:variable name="Work to do" select="DocumentElement/Working[(worktype='wash' or worktype='clean' worktype='sweep') and (attendance= 'Present' or attendance = 'permit')]"></xsl:variable>

 public string milestonebugstype()
    {
        string ms_bugtype;
        string msbugs = CommonHelper.Getmilestonebug();
        string[] milestonebugs = msbugs.Split(',');
        List<string> milestone_bugs = new List<string>();
        foreach (string milestonebugtype in milestonebugs)
        {
            milestone_bugs.Add("task_type=" + "'" + milestonebugtype + "'");
        }
        ms_bugtype = string.Join(" or ", milestone_bugs.ToArray());
        return ms_bugtype;
    }
  string milestone_bugs = milestonebugtype();
  outputXml += "<WorkType>"+milestone_bugs+"</WorkType>";

 <xsl:variable name="Works" select="documentelement/worktype"></xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="Work to do" select="DocumentElement/Working[($works) and (attendance= 'Present' or attendance = 'permit')]">   </xsl:variable>
```

I would like to externalize the **worktype='wash' or worktype='clean' worktype='sweep'** from the database I retrieved the data but don't know how to do in XSL. Here worktype is taken from table and I want to load 'wash','clean' dynamically through XML. Please help me

Comment: Please show us an example of the XML input and point to the location of the "dynamic" values you want to use. See: [mcve]

Comment: I have updated my code above see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a old c# project i have used <xsl:param name="paramname"></xsl:param> to pass parameter XslCompiledTransform.Transform. I passed simple types as strings